# ngTable - define custom sorting order

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, columnsorting

I'm using `ngTable` to display some data and I need an initial way of sorting order to display it at page load. There's the normal option to set the sorting, for example `sorting: {color: "asc"}`, this will sort the `color` column alphabetically. Assuming this is my table data:

```
    var x = [
  {name: "allen", age: 33, color:"green"},
  {name: "jon", age: 23, color:"blonde"},
  {name: "silver", age: 54, color:"yellow"},
  {name: "james", age: 52, color:"grey"},
  {name: "flint", age: 25, color:"pink"},
  {name: "billy", age: 31, color:"blonde"},
  {name: "bones", age: 47, color:"grey"},
  {name: "michael", age: 35, color:"green"},
  {name: "jackson", age: 234, color:"yellow"},
  {name: "leonardo", age: 12, color:"brown"},
  {name: "dicaprio", age: 73, color:"pink"},
  {name: "sylvester", age: 35, color:"blonde"}
];
```

How can I set the initial sort order of the `color` column by custom order, such as first all `green`, then all `pink` then all `yellow` and last `grey`.
This is my code so far:

```
  function demoController(NgTableParams, simpleList) {
        var names = [
      {name: "allen", age: 33, color:"green"},
      {name: "jon", age: 23, color:"blonde"},
      {name: "silver", age: 54, color:"yellow"},
      {name: "james", age: 52, color:"grey"},
      {name: "flint", age: 25, color:"pink"},
      {name: "billy", age: 31, color:"blonde"},
      {name: "bones", age: 47, color:"grey"},
      {name: "michael", age: 35, color:"green"},
      {name: "jackson", age: 234, color:"yellow"},
      {name: "leonardo", age: 12, color:"brown"},
      {name: "dicaprio", age: 73, color:"pink"},
      {name: "sylvester", age: 35, color:"blonde"}
    ];
    this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
      // initial sort order
      sorting: { color: ["green","pink","yellow","grey"] } 
    }, {
      dataset: names
    });
  }
```

[Code is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwpEjy?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the sort attribute in the directive?

```
<td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
```

Comment: Do you mean something like that?
`<td title="'Name'" filter="{ color: 'green'}" sortable="'name'">`